# Embedded youtube videos' parameters not working in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set some parameters to my youtube video that I embedded in a WKWebView with the "loadHTMLString" method, but some of them are not working. Also, I'm trying to not allow the fullscreen, so when the user presses the red button to start the video, it doesn't go to fullscreen.

This is the code I have

```
let videoEmbedString = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe frameBorder=\"0\" height=\""

    let one = "500px" + "\" width=\"" + "100%" + "\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"

    let id = "JhGxCMZ1E8k"

    let parameters = "?showinfo=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&loop=1&playlist=\(id)&controls=0\"></iframe></body></html>"

    let final = videoEmbedString + one + id + parameters

    webView2 = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    webView2.loadHTMLString(final, baseURL: nil)
    view.addSubview(webView2)
```

I do not know if you have to put the parameters in a certain order to work, or you have to add something else. 
Right now the parameter that doesn't work is the "modestbranding" and the parameter that doesn't allow the fullscreen that I do not know how to put.

Also, here is the API I'm using for reference:https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=es-419#autoplay

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Why are you using WebKit to play YouTube. Why don’t you go for YouTube iOS library. Please refer  https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: That library is in Objective-C, and I'm working with swift

Comment: So what? You can install it using cocopods

Comment: It works perfectly fine with swift. I have done it

Comment: Thank you!!! I did it and now the video runs perfectly!!!